# CSS3 blur effect does not work as expected

Tags: jquery, css

I have an simple modal window.

```
#overlay {
z-index: 99998;
position: fixed;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
cursor: pointer;
display: block; 
}

#modalDialog {
border-radius: 3px;
width: 620px;
position: fixed; 
top: 10%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -310px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
color: #505260;
display: none; 
opacity: 0; 
z-index: 99999; 
}
```

Its work fine. I want to blur background with animate, but something wrong happened.
This is the code:

```
 $('#overlay')
                .css('filter', 'blur(3px)')
                .css('webkitFilter', 'blur(3px)')
                .css('mozFilter', 'blur(3px)')
                .css('oFilter', 'blur(3px)')
                .css('msFilter', 'blur(3px)')
                .css('transition', 'all 0.5s ease-out')
                .css('-webkit-transition', 'all 0.5s ease-out')
                .css('-moz-transition', 'all 0.5s ease-out')
                .css('-o-transition', 'all 0.5s ease-out');
```

As you can see on image with dialog blur effect works nice, but with background - blur only edges.
Fiddle -  [jsfiddle.net/zgzwaucw/1](http://jsfiddle.net/zgzwaucw/1)

Pls go to fiddle, where you can see that edges are blurred. I want to blur background.

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle? Or show us something live.

Comment: I will try. Wait a few minutes.

Comment: @Mario We need to see the markup as well.

Comment: @Mario rngst_overlay ? pls post a fiddle or post ur html markup as well

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zgzwaucw/ - there is blurred dialog;                                                         $('#modalDialog') .css('filter', 'blur(3px)') ....... Change selector on $(#overlay) and you see that edges is blured. You can change blur value to 30 to see result.

Comment: There you can see what is happen http://jsfiddle.net/zgzwaucw/1/

Comment: See - http://jsfiddle.net/zgzwaucw/3/ Looks like it works fine.

Comment: It is actually working, if you have something in there to blur: http://jsfiddle.net/zgzwaucw/2/

Comment: I think you should look into  `filter:opacity` that might be what you want in this scenario

Comment: Yes, its work with image, but i want to blur content, which under this modal. Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/zgzwaucw/4/  . Its mean that i need to place all my content in overlay div?

Comment: You can't blur content that isn't in the div that's being blurred. I think you might need another approach.

Comment: There i found what i want. Can you understand how its works? http://callbackhunter.com/#callbackhunter-dialog

Comment: @Mario: The entire page is placed in a div element, and the blur effect is applied on that div. The modal dialog is placed *outside* that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blur filter applies to the element that you set it on. If you apply blur to the overlay, then only the overlay will be blurred, not the content underneath it. To achieve the effect you're referring to, you need to put all the contents of your page into a single "wrapper" div and apply the blur filter to it.

Here is an example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".modal-dialog").show();
  $("#contents").addClass("blurred");
}, 1500);
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px "Sans Serif";
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blurred {
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
}

#contents {
  width: 660px;
  height: 201px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5uHk.jpg);
  background-size: 660px auto;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  top: 100px;
  left: 330px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  padding: 33px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contents">
  <!-- Put all the site contents in this div -->
</div>

<div class="modal-dialog" style="display: none">
  This is a modal dialog
</div>
```